# Yoast Plugin Won't Detect Content from Shortcode in a Custom Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a pretty simple shortcode that contains html and php and wrapped it between the following code and used the shortcode inside a WordPress post. I went ahead to create custom plugin for which contains the shortcode.

I am having a challenge whereby the Yoast plugin is unable to detect the content of the shortcode. I know the shortcode is working perfectly, it's just that Yoast won't pull the right word count. The shortcode really contains a basic select query that fetches data from the database.

I found an article that mentioned Yoast only detects content that goes into the default WordPress editor and may not detect content from themes and plugins unless the developer adds the functionality. I'm the one doing this even as I learn.

The shortcode template I'm using:

```
function test_shortcode() {

    ob_start();

    ....
    
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'myshortcd', 'test_shortcode' );
```

Is there some code I need to add to the basic shortcode to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something that is super easy to do because it requires tapping in to Yoast's javascript API. Here is the article explaining how to do it:

https://developer.yoast.com/customization/yoast-seo/adding-custom-data-analysis/

Yoast used to have a backend hook for this, but now it's all handled on the frontend.

An alternative approach would be to use a third-party service that scrapes the content as its rendered, which ultimately is going to give you better content analysis anyway. They aren't always cheap services though. Here's one our SEO team uses:

https://www.clearscope.io/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have understood all that except for this bit `addContent( data ) {
        data += "Hello, I'm some additional data!";
        return data ;
    }` Since my code is in PHP. How do you replace the "Hello, I'm some additional data!" with the shortcode? Would it work if I replaced that bit with the shortcode above? Correct me if this is wrong. The part which I want rendered is the shortcode in the question so was wondering if it would render if I replaced that part only. The rest of the steps appear straightforward.

Comment: So, that's where things would get difficult. One way you could do that is with a `wp_ajax` endpoint that retrieves what you want from the backend.

Comment: It really depends on what your shortcode is outputting.

Comment: I suspected this is beyond me. But I'll try to give a shot though.

Comment: My code is some really select db queries and html for displaying on page.

Comment: It's going to be complicated and their sample code isn't even going to work as is because if there's no way to get the content without pulling it from the backend, you'll need to use AJAX but since that's asynchronous, you'll need to use some more advanced ES6 to await the response.